# How to prevent multiline TextField from scrolling away when pointer is pressed elsewhere

Tags: codenameone

I have a multiline `TextField`

```
TextField msgField = new TextField();
msgField.setMaxSize(10000);
msgField.setGrowLimit(5);
msgField.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
```

The `TextField` is the only focusable element in the form, and gets focus from straight after `form.show()` onwards

When this `TextField` contains more lines than its limit (5 lines), and the pointer is pressed away from the `TextField`, the `TextField`'s content scrolls away even though if another key is pressed it continues writing where the cursor was. On Android, line formatting changes (extra spacing is added between lines).

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

**Screenshots** (from Android, even though this also happens in the Simulator. I include Android because it shows the line formatting issue)

Before pressing away:

[image]

After pressing away (notice scrolling has changed and line spacing has increased):

[image]

Edit: My intuition tells me I need to override `TextField`'s `pointerReleased`. But how?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. The multi-line text field should be scrolled vertically to the current cursor position. I suggest filing an issue with this